# Any bigger fonts for php?

Tags: php, fonts, gd, dynamic-image-generation

As described [here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php) you can use

> imageloadfont (file)

to get a font in PHP, e.g. for writing onto a generated image.
Now I was wondering where to get such files for fonts, like is there some sort of converter around to convert from "normal" fonts to this weird format PHP uses? Or is there some sort of collection of such fonts?

I need this for my captcha-generator which needs a font that is bigger than the biggest standard PHP font available.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use TrueType fonts instead of PHP's internal format? Is it because of the bitmap effect?

Comment: @Pekka: Firstly I hadn't realized I could use truetype and secondly I was kinda interested in PHP's weird format cause it's something new for me, so I'd still be happy to get my hands on some fonts of that format or on a tutorial or thelike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Nice True Type fonts using php to make an Image Captcha, and on my website I have a really nice example of how to make one!

http://phpsnips.com/43/Advanced-Image-Captcha#.UNx6mNdQC0x

Comment: This should work. Didn't realize I could just use truetype. silly me.